# How to use TouchID to bind this account to this device

Tags: ios

I would like to use Apple's fingerprint payment function, but how to bind the account, equipment, fingerprints of the three together, so as to ensure that the next time to open the fingerprint payment to enter the device can be used directly to pay fingerprints, and in different devices On the first use will remind you whether to open the fingerprint payment.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple, current don't expose any information of stored fingerprints. After, finger print prompt, OS validates it with all the stored fingerprints in the device and send success or failure token. So, you cant really bind a particular fingerprint with account.

Comment: In fact, I just want to fingerprintPay the status of the opening or not to bind the account, rather than the fingerprint and account binding together.